# How to avoid SQL query timeout error when open transaction is there?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have used below query to retrieve customer details from database.

**Method 1:**

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 'X' From CUSTOMER Where CustId = @Code AND Status = 'D')
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER 
    SET Status = 'L' 
    WHERE CustId = @BorrowerCode AND ISNULL(Borrower,'') = 'Y'

    SELECT CustId, MobileNo, PlaceDesc
    FROM CUSTOMER C 
    JOIN PLACE P ON C.FKID = P.Pk_Id
    WHERE Cust_Id = @Code AND C.Status = 'L'
END
COMMIT TRAN
```

**Method 2:**

```
BEGIN TRAN
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 'X' From CUSTOMER Where CustId = @Code AND Status = 'D')
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER 
    SET Status = 'L' 
    WHERE CustId = @BorrowerCode AND ISNULL(Borrower,'') = 'Y'

    SELECT CustId, MobileNo, PlaceDesc
    FROM CUSTOMER C With(NoLock) 
    JOIN PLACE P With(NoLock) ON C.FKID = P.Pk_Id
    WHERE Cust_Id = @Code AND C.Status = 'L'
 END
 COMMIT TRAN
```

If there is an open transaction in database, the query will fail with a timeout for method 1. Is it good practice to use NoLock inside transaction?

Comment: `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`

Comment: @Devart, If I use TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT in Method 1, query timeout will not occur? Is it correct?

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: you also can make update sargable..

Comment: UPDATE CUSTOMER 
    SET Status = 'L' 
    WHERE CustId = @BorrowerCode AND Borrower = 'Y' and borrower is not null

Comment: It'll also help to keep your transactions small - you can just wrap the update statement in a transaction, do the if and select need to be in there?

Comment: @marc_s, If I omit nolock what is the alternate method to overcome timeout issue when transaction in open state?

Comment: @RGS: as Devart mentioned - look into the snapshot isolation level - that'll probably be your best bet. Or you can use the `READPAST` table hint to just skip rows that are locked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things..

1.First of all your update is not sargable,you can try to rewrite it as below

```
UPDATE CUSTOMER 
SET Status = 'L' 
WHERE CustId = @BorrowerCode AND Borrower = 'Y'
```

2.Time out has pretty huge limit,25 times query cost.so even with this limit,if you are getting time out ,then there must be some thing wrong and we are trying to apply bandage with nolock.setting isolation level to snapshot ,will not result in blockings of select ,but it comes with a cost of tempDB usage,scan issues(see link below for more..).Further isolation level wont apply to DDL/DML statements ,they are just for select statements and in your case ,an open transaction may mean some DDL/DML running for so long.

In summary,i wont use nolock,but i would rather try to see why timeout happens and also changing isolation level requires some testing as well

**References:**
http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said in second point. If I omit nolock what is the alternate method to overcome timeout issue when transaction in open state?

Comment: I meant to say ,you need to look out actual problem of time out occurring instead of applying no lock bandage.